# If $f$ pulls back closed sets to closed sets then $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, continuity

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$. Let $F$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$. It is given that $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed whenever $F$ is closed. Prove that $f$ is continuous.

> Proof:

Since $F$ and $f^{-1}(F)$ are closed, they contain all their respective limit points. Consider an arbitrary vector $y\in F$, then $\exists$ a sequence $\{y_n\}$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} y_n = y$. By the Axiom of choice, there exists a point $x_n\in f^{-1}(F)$ such that $f(x_n)=y_n$ for all $n$. Since $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed, $f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n)=f(x)=y$. Also, $y=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} y_n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)=f(x)$. Thus $f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$, so $f$ is continuous by sequential continuity.

Please let me know if my proof contains any errors.

Comment: Axiom of choice is not necessary, that argument is straight from definition of preimage. Notice $f^{-1}$ is not necessary a function (and you don't need it to be one).

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your argument, as pointed out in the comment.

To show that $f$ is continuous, it suffices to show that $f^{-1}(G)$ is open whenever $G$ is open.

If $G$ is open, then $G^c$ is closed. By assumption, then, $f^{-1}(G^c)$ is closed. But $f^{-1}(G^c) = (f^{-1}(G))^c$. Therefore, $f^{-1}(G)$ is open, as desired.

Comment: How do we know that $f$ is defined on $G^c$?

Comment: $G$ and $G^c$ are subsets of the codomain of $f$, so I'm not sure I understand your question. Also, your notation in the OP seems ambiguous. Is $F$ the codomain of $f$ or is $F$ any closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$? It seems to me the question should read: Consider a function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've corrected that. So, in my understanding, if the codomain of $f$ is not all of $\mathbb{R}^m$, $f$ may not be defined on $G^c$, correct?

Did you spot any errors in my proof, other than what was pointed out by Luke?

Comment: I think you might be a bit confused about what $f^{-1}(F)$ means. This is defined to be the _set_ of all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x) \in F \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: Yes, I know that.

Comment: Ok. The logic of your proof seems flawed anyhow. You want to show that if $x_n \to x$ then $f(x_n) \to f(x)$, right? But you start by choosing a sequence $y_n \in F \subset \mathbb{R}^m$...

Comment: Yes, but why would that be flawed? I begin with a sequence in $F$ and then I pull that sequence back to $f^{-1}(F)$.